# MySQL update rows. Need to update lots of unique rows

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP scripts on my mySQL database. What I have is an inventory of products that is being pulled for a search page. I have this working fine, and my search page is working flawlessly. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to update the stock of each product in the database. I have a new file that needs to match up with the product number and then replace the data in one column of the mysql database. Much like this below

mysql database:

ProductNumber..................ProductStock

12345678....................................1

New file:

12345678..................5

Basically I need the new file to match with the product number on the mysql and replace the product stock with the new number. All of this in PHP.

Comment: Let's see what you have so far. What problems are you encountering?

Comment: do you mean that you are keeping a running total of an inventory in your product table?  So every time you sell an item you subtract from the total and every time you buy an item you add to the total?  If so that breaks normalization rules.

Comment: @Leslie No, I am not keeping a running total, but the columns need to be updated daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how many rows you got in that database. Usually individual UPDATEs are pretty slow.

You can

- load your "new stocks" file into a temporary table using LOAD DATA INFILE
- make an UPDATE using a JOIN to set the values in your products table

This will be a few orders of magnitude faster.

Update with the syntax to use on mysql :

```
UPDATE products p JOIN temp_products t ON (p.id=t.id) SET p.stock = t.stock;
```

Note that you need special privileges for LOAD DATA INFILE. 
You can also use LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL (check the docs).

Or, you can parse the file with PHP, generate an INSERT with multi-values in a temp table, and do a joined update. This will be a little slower than LOAD DATA INFILE, but much much faster than doing 27000 queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE table_products SET ProductStock=5 WHERE ProductNumber=12345678';
mysql_query($sql);
```

So basically: use an UPDATE statement for the database.

How does the file look?

Comment: I have used this command, but the file I am working with is a fixed length text file. Basically I need to run this command for every row of the text file. So I need to feed it into the php. I may need to look at @Shahal Tharique's method and use the explode() tag. Any ideas how to use this with a fixed length text file?

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to open the file, use `explode()` and then use `preg_match` as per the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's load data local infile to do this. Write a small import script and run it on a cron daily. Is the stock file in csv format?

An example script would be as follows

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$stock_file = $dir . "files". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."stock.csv";

$stock_query = "
    load data local infile \"{$stock_file}\"
    replace into table products
    fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"'
    lines terminated by '\n'
    ignore 1 lines
    (ProductNumber,ProductStock);
";

$m->query($stock_query);
```

Things to consider would be what the fields are terminated by and enclosed by. Also the ignore 1 lines is there to ignore the header row if the file has one.